# CircleCi, TestContainers using Docker Executor with remote Docker environment

Tags: circleci, testcontainers

I'm running Testcontainers on remote docker environment in CircleCi the opened ports on the containers are not available. Can this work without reverting to the Machine executor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Note: this is obsolete, Testcontainers will now just work on Circleci**

As of April 2023 this seems no longer necessary, the ports are bound and exposed on localhost since all remote docker and docker executors run on the same VM. See: https://discuss.circleci.com/t/changes-to-remote-docker-reporting-pricing/47759/1

You can use Testcontainers with a `docker` executor, but there are limitations due to the fact
that this will be a remote docker environment that is firewalled and only reachable through SSH.

Conceptually you need to follow these steps:

- Add `setup-remote-docker` to `.circleci/config.yml`
- Add a login step if you need private container images during test.
- Set the environment variable `TESTCONTAINERS_HOST_OVERRIDE=localhost`. Ports are mapped to localhost through SSH.
- Create tunnels into the remote docker for every exposed port.
  The reason is that the remote docker is firewalled and only available through
  `ssh remote-docker`. In the example below `.circleci/autoforward.py` runs in the background, monitors docker port
  mappings and creates SSH port forwards to localhost on the fly.

A sample config `.circleci/config.yml`

```yaml
version: 2.1
jobs:
    test:
        docker:
            # choose an image that has: 
            #    ssh, java, git, docker-cli, tar, gzip, python3
            - image: cimg/openjdk:16.0.0
        steps:
            - checkout
            - setup_remote_docker:
                  version: 20.10.2
                  docker_layer_caching: true
            - run:
                  name: Docker login
                  command: |
                      # access private container images during tests
                      echo ${DOCKER_PASS} | \
                        docker login ${DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL} \
                          -u ${DOCKER_USER} \ 
                          --password-stdin
            - run:
                  name: Setup Environment Variables
                  command: |
                      echo "export TESTCONTAINERS_HOST_OVERRIDE=localhost" \
                        >> $BASH_ENV
            - run:
                  name: Testcontainers tunnel
                  background: true
                  command: .circleci/autoforward.py
            - run: ./gradlew clean test --stacktrace
workflows:
    test:
        jobs:
            - test
```

And the script handling the port forwards: .circleci/autoforward.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import dataclasses
import threading
import sys
import signal
import subprocess
import json
import re
import time


@dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True)
class Forward:
    port: int

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)

    @staticmethod
    def parse_list(ports):
        r = []
        for port in ports.split(","):
            port_splits = port.split("->")
            if len(port_splits) < 2:
                continue
            host, ports = Forward.parse_host(port_splits[0], "localhost")
            for port in ports:
                r.append(Forward(port))
        return r

    @staticmethod
    def parse_host(s, default_host):
        s = re.sub("/.*$", "", s)
        hp = s.split(":")
        if len(hp) == 1:
            return default_host, Forward.parse_ports(hp[0])
        if len(hp) == 2:
            return hp[0], Forward.parse_ports(hp[1])
        return None, []

    @staticmethod
    def parse_ports(ports):
       port_range = ports.split("-")
       start = int(port_range[0])
       end = int(port_range[0]) + 1
       if len(port_range) > 2 or len(port_range) < 1:
           raise RuntimeError(f"don't know what to do with ports {ports}")
       if len(port_range) == 2:
           end = int(port_range[1]) + 1
       return list(range(start, end))

class PortForwarder:
    def __init__(self, forward, local_bind_address="127.0.0.1"):
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(
            [
                "ssh",
                "-N",
                f"-L{local_bind_address}:{forward.port}:localhost:{forward.port}",
                "remote-docker",
            ]
        )

    def stop(self):
        self.process.kill()


class DockerForwarder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.running = threading.Event()
        self.running.set()

    def start(self):
        forwards = {}
        try:
            while self.running.is_set():
                new_forwards = self.container_config()
                existing_forwards = list(forwards.keys())
                for forward in new_forwards:
                    if forward in existing_forwards:
                        existing_forwards.remove(forward)
                    else:
                        print(f"adding forward {forward}")
                        forwards[forward] = PortForwarder(forward)

                for to_clean in existing_forwards:
                    print(f"stopping forward {to_clean}")
                    forwards[to_clean].stop()
                    del forwards[to_clean]
                time.sleep(0.8)
        finally:
            for forward in forwards.values():
                forward.stop()

    @staticmethod
    def container_config():
        def cmd(cmd_array):
            out = subprocess.Popen(
                cmd_array,
                universal_newlines=True,
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
            )
            out.wait()
            return out.communicate()[0]

        try:
            stdout = cmd(["docker", "ps", "--format", "'{{json .}}'"])
            stdout = stdout.replace("'", "")
            configs = map(lambda l: json.loads(l), stdout.splitlines())
            forwards = []
            for c in configs:
                if c is None or c["Ports"] is None:
                    continue
                ports = c["Ports"].strip()
                if ports == "":
                    continue
                forwards += Forward.parse_list(ports)
            return forwards
        except RuntimeError:
            print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
            return []

    def stop(self):
        print("stopping")
        self.running.clear()


def main():
    forwarder = DockerForwarder()

    def handler(*_):
        forwarder.stop()

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)

    forwarder.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```